# Why doesn't my code for making a chessboard in Processing work?

Tags: processing

I'm new to programming! I'm trying to make a chessboard using Processing (a language using similar syntax as Java).

Why is this not working?

````
void setup(){
  //5.b In setup() set the size to 350, 350 
  size(350,350);
  
  for (int y = 0; y < 8; y = y++){
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
      if ((y+x+1) % 2 == 0 ){
        fill(255);
      }else{
        fill(0);
      }
      rect(50*x,50*y,50,50);
      }
      
    }

}

```
````

Comment: Could you show what you expect to see drawn on the screen, and what comes out instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The program is not working, because of this for loop, which runs forever:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 8; y = y++){
```

The reason is that the assigment `y = y++` does the following:

1. it evaluates the value of the right side, which will be `y`
2. it processes the ++ operator, incrementing the value of `y`
3. it processes the assigment, i.e. it assigns to `y` the value calculated in step 1, which is `y`

Therefore, the value of `y` never changes and the for loop never terminates.

Change it to this and it should work:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++){
```

Comment: Used 30 minutes yesterday and could not understand why it would not work. Thank you for solving my problem!